# Laravel mix не сохраняет css-файл

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Чистый Laravel, сделал `npm install`, в webpack.mix.js прописал

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css');
```

Запускаю `npm run hot`, но в файле `css/app.css` ничего не меняется. Более того, удалил стандартный файл, который идет "из коробки", после этого ничего в папке css не появляется. Как быть? Что я делаю не так?

UPD сделал `npm run watch`, все заработало. В чем разница между watch и hot?

Answer (score 1):

`watch` - это вотчер файлов, который производит перекомпиляцию при изменеии файлов на подобии `gulp` только через вебпак.

В случае с `hot` запускается механизм HMR (hot module replacement), который использовать удобно при разработки CPA или приложения с рендерингом на клиенте. HRM работает примерно так: следит за изменеием файлов и при изменении модуля он "перезагружает" именно этот модуль с его зависимостями, сохраняя состояние приложения. Такая "горячая" перезагрузка модуля осуществляется по вебсокету. При этом стили добавляются непосредсвенно в разметку также для горячей замены

Процесс разработки с `hot` наиболее удобен при разработке на `vue` c использованием однофайловых компонентов.

Это одна из классных фич вебпака, когда не нужно даже перезагружать страницу и в процессе разработки изменения кода применяются практически моментально.

Comment: Ох, я даже и не знал. Пилил даже SPA на vue, так приходилось каждый раз после изменения "руками" доводить до того состояния, в котором нужно было что-то тестировать. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: пожалуйста. Правда я для CPA с vue и laravel сам настраивал вебпак на основе vue-cli шаблона `webpack`